# Move object in silverlight canvas

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyGameSilverlight.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" KeyDown="OnKeyDown">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

            <Canvas x:Name="c1" Background="Green" Margin="0,0,130,80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.463,0.5">
                <Rectangle x:Name="obj" Height="60" Width="80" Canvas.Left="45" Canvas.Top="45" Fill="Aqua" />
            </Canvas>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[Code Behind]

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Right:
                    Canvas.SetLeft(obj, Canvas.GetLeft(obj) + 20);
                    break;

                case Key.Left:
                    Canvas.SetLeft(obj, Canvas.GetLeft(obj) - 20);
                    break;
                // more here
            }
        }
```

I have this code for simple rectangle in the canvas. Now i want to move this rectangle on on key press.
For example when i press the right arrow key the rectangle should move 20px right form its initial position.

What is the code behind code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties in code behind by the static methods [Canvas.GetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.getleft%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [Canvas.GetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.gettop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(obj) + 20;
double top = Canvas.GetTop(obj) + 20;
Canvas.SetLeft(obj, left);
Canvas.SetTop(obj, top);
```

---

It seems that the question was about how to receive or handle keyboard input. You would have to attach (for example) a KeyDown handler, but you have to know that a UIElement needs to have the keyboard focus in order to receive key events. As neither Rectangle nor Canvas are focusable (see [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903954%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), you may attach the handler to your MainPage:

```
<UserControl ... KeyDown="OnKeyDown">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Name="obj" .../>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

In the handler you would handle the individual keys like this:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Right:
            Canvas.SetLeft(obj, Canvas.GetLeft(obj) + 20);
            break;
        // more here
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this but what should be the method name?

i tried private void LayoutRoot_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            

            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(obj) + 20;
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(obj) + 20;
                Canvas.SetLeft(obj, left);
                Canvas.SetTop(obj, top);
            }
}

and

private void c1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: How would I possibly know that? You haven't told that in your question. Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry. More important, did you see my edit? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes i am looking for this, but unfortunately it's not working. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Did you click into the page? It does not have focus by default.

Comment: Yes i did not click before. thank you for catching that. Also is there any code to do the focusing?

Comment: Please read [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903954%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). There is a [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.focus(v=vs.95).aspx) method in class Control.